# Distribution of the Number of Points in Poisson-Voronoi Tessellation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I would like to ask a question about the independence when two Poisson point processes associate with each other. The details are as follows:

We consider two independent homogeneous Poisson point processes in $\mathbb{R}^2$, denoted as $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$, with intensity $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively. Assume the points belonging to $\Psi_2$ connect to the nearest points in $\Psi_1$. Therefore, for each point in $\Psi_1$, it has $K$ points (which can be from $0$ to $\infty$) connected.

Another description is $\Psi_1$ forms a Poisson-Voronoi tessellation, and the number of points   (belonging to $\Psi_2$) in each cell is $K$.

The question is whether the $K$ is i.i.d. for each node? And how to obtain the distribution of $K$.

Thanks in advance. Comments and discussions are welcome if I didn't state clearly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the distribution of $K$ has no explicit expression but has bounds, see Theorem 4 in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.1282&rep=rep1&type=ps

Comment: Hi @Tulip, Thank you for your answer. I have read this paper before, but I remember that in this paper, they didn't justify that $K$ in different cells are independent or not. Have you ever saw some proofs about this? Thanks.

Comment: Once we fix the first process the number of points in each cell must be independent. Anyway, I have just found that some guys found a elegant approximation for the distribution of K (lemma 1 in "Downlink Capacity and Base Station Density in Cellular Networks":  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2992.pdf)